# Is $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)\cap \mathbb{Q}((x))=\mathbb{Q}(x)$? [unsolved (even though we earlier thought it was)]

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

Fix the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}((x))$ for this question to make sense. I know that $\mathbb{Q}((x)) \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}(x)}$ has elements that are not in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ (in analogy to the "algebraic p-adics"). So I wondered, if we intersect with something even smaller, $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, would then the result be $\mathbb{Q}(x)$?

More neatly, does $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)\cap \mathbb{Q}((x))=\mathbb{Q}(x)$?

Comment: What is the notation $\mathbb Q((x))$ for?

Comment: The field of Laurent series. $\mathbb{Q}((x))=Quot(\mathbb{Q}[[x]])$, the quotient field of the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This follows from Lemma 27.9 (bottom of page 150) in Milne's Lectures on Etale Cohomology (http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/lec.html), which is: For an extension of fields $K/k$, $k[[t]]\cap K(t)=k(t)$. Merely observe that you can multiply an element of $k((t))$ by a power of $t$ to get it in $k[[t]]$ and that a rational function divided by a power of $t$ is still a rational function. Of course, you still need to understand Milne's proof! (NB: his Bourbaki reference should be to exercise 1 in IV.4, at least in the English translation.)

Comment: Dear Nicole: I suggest that you change the title (since you have accepted an answer).

Comment: Dear @BR, you have misquoted Milne. Indeed your equality $k[[t]]\cap K(t)=k(t)$ is false because it would imply $k(t)\subset k[[t]]$, which is false (for example $\frac 1t\notin k[[t]]$).

Comment: Indeed! I don't know what I was thinking. It should be $k[[t]]\cap K(t)\subset k(t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any automorphism $\sigma$ of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, extend it to an automorphism $s$ of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}((x))$ by acting on coefficients:
$$s\left(\sum a_n x^n\right) = \sum \sigma(a_n) x^n$$

I assert the following:

- The subfield of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ fixed by all $s$'s is $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ (note that each $s$ really is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$)
- The subfield of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}((x))$ fixed by all $s$'s is $\mathbb{Q}((x))$

Therefore, any element of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ that is an element of $\mathbb{Q}((x))$ must also be an element of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.

One method to see the former assertion is to write elements in a normal form such as a scalar times a ratio (in lowest terms) of monic polynomials. Since the $s$'s act on the coefficients, elements in the fixed field must have all rational coefficients.

Comment: I think you should detail why $(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x))^{Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})} = \mathbb{Q}(x)$.

Comment: I had hoped it would be clear enough -- but after thinking it through, I guess there are enough troublesome ways to try and attack the problem that it's worth sketching a relatively pain-free method.

Comment: It is true that some details are missing (giving a consistent way to extend $Gal(\mathbb{Q})$), but they are clear to me, and it is the most elegant of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

## New answer

The answer is yes.

I think the $\mathbb Q$ and $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ are red herrings.

For instance, if $L/K$ is a field extension and $X$ an indeterminate, one can ask if the inclusion 
$$
L(X)\cap K((X))\subset K(X)
$$ 
holds. (The answer is yes.) This is clearly equivalent to 
$$
L(X)\cap K[[X]]\subset K(X).
$$
Now let $f$ be in $K[[X]]$, and let $F$ be $K$ or $L$. Then $f$ is in $F(X)$ if and only if the linear equation 
$$
p-fq=0
$$ 
has a nonzero solution $(p,q)\in F[X]^2$, and we see that the problem makes sense of $K$ and $L$ are commutative rings.

By reasoning like this, we see that the claim boils down to the following statement, which is Corollary $3$ of Proposition II.$3.7$ in Bourbaki's **Algèbre**.

> If $A$ is an associative ring with $1$, if $X$ is a free right $A$-module, and if $(Y_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of left $A$-modules, then the natural map 
>   $$
> \phi:X\ \underset{A}{\otimes}\ \prod_{i\in I}\ Y_i\to\prod_{i\in I}\ \left(X\underset{A}{\otimes} Y_i\right)
> $$
>   is injective.

Proof. Identifying $X$ to a direct sum $\bigoplus_{j\in J}A$ we can write view $\phi$ as a map 
$$
\phi:U:=\bigoplus_{j\in J}\ \prod_{i\in I}\ Y_i\ \to\ 
\prod_{i\in I}\ \bigoplus_{j\in J}\ Y_i=:V
$$
Now $U$ and $V$ are subgroups of 
$$
W:=\prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}Y_i. 
$$
More precisely, an element
$$
y=(y_{ij})_{(i,j)\in I\times J}\in W
$$
is in $U$ if and only if there is a finite subset $J(y)$ of $J$ such that $y_{ij}=0$ if $j$ is not in $J(y)$.

Similarly, $y$ is in $V$ if and only if there is, for each $i$ in $I$, a finite subset $J_i(y)$ of $J$ such that $y_{ij}=0$ if $j$ is not in $J_i(y)$.

So we have $U\subset V$, and it is easy to see that $\phi$ is the inclusion.

## Old answer

The answer is yes, as follows from the observation below.

Let $A\subset B$ be commutative rings, $x$ an indeterminate, and $f$ an element of $A[[x]]$. Consider the $A[x]$-linear map 
$$
\phi:A[x]\times A[x]\to A[[x]],\quad(P,Q)\mapsto P-fQ,
$$
and the $B[x]$-linear map 
$$
\psi:B[x]\times B[x]\to B[[x]],\quad(P,Q)\mapsto P-fQ.
$$

> If $B$ is $A$-free and $\phi$ injective, then $\psi$ is injective.

Indeed, $\psi$ is the composition of the $B[x]$-linear extension 
$$
\phi_B:B[x]\times B[x]\to B\otimes_AA[[x]]
$$
of $\phi$ and the natural map 
$$
\theta:B\otimes_AA[[x]]\to B[[x]].
$$
Then $\phi_B$ is injective because $B$ is $A$-flat, and $\theta$ is injective because $B$ is $A$-free.

**EDIT A.** Assume now that $A$ and $B$ are fields. We claim 
$$
B(x)\cap A((x))\subset A(x).
$$
(The reverse inclusion is obvious.) It suffices to show 
$$
B(x)\cap A[[x]]\subset A(x).
$$
Let $f$ be in $A[[x]]$. Then $f$ is in $A(x)$ if and only if $\phi$ is not injective, and $f$ is in $B(x)$ if and only if $\psi$ is not injective.

**EDIT B.** Let me prove the injectivity of $\theta$. Let $(b_i)$ be an $A$-basis of $B$, and let $f$ be in $\ker\theta$. Then $f$ can be written in a unique way as 
$$
f=\sum_i\ b_i\otimes f_i
$$
with $f_i\in A[[x]]$ for all $i$, and $f_i=0$ for almost all $i$. Put 
$$
f_i=\sum_{n\ge0}\ a_{in}\ x^n
$$
with $a_{in}\in A$. Then we have 
$$
0=\theta(f)=\sum_{n\ge0}\ \sum_i\ b_i\ a_{in}\ x^n.
$$
This implies 
$$
\sum_i\ b_i\ a_{in}=0
$$
for all $n$, and thus $a_{in}=0$ for all $i$ and all $n$.

**EDIT C.** Let $A\subset B$ be commutative rings and $x$ an indeterminate. The purpose of this edit is to define $A(x),B(x)$ and $A((x))$ in such a way that

(a) the definitions compatible with the usual ones if $A$ and $B$ are fields,

(b) the equality 
$$
B(x)\cap A((x))=A(x).
$$
holds if $B$ free over $A$.

Define $A((x))$ as the ring of Laurent series with coefficients in $A$.

Say that $f\in A((x))$ is in $A(x)$ if there are $P,Q$ in $A[x]$ satisfying $Qf=P$. Then $A(x)$ is a subring of $A((x))$ containing $A[x]$, and the above arguments show that (b) holds.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be the field of Puiseux series over $\bar{\mathbb Q}$. This is an algebraic closed field containing $\mathbb Q((x))$ and $\bar{\mathbb Q}(x)$.

Then :

- The elements of $L$ lying in $\mathbb Q((x))$ are the elements with **rational coefficients** ;
- The elements of $L$ lying in $\bar{\mathbb Q}(x)$ are the elements with no fractional power for which the sequence of coefficient satisfy a **linear recurrence with constant coefficients in $\bar{\mathbb Q}$** ;
- The elements of $L$ lying in $\mathbb Q(x)$ are the elements with no fractional power, **rational coefficients** and for which the sequence of coefficient satisfy a **linear recurrence with constant coefficients in $\mathbb Q$**.

So it is enough to prove that if a sequence of rational numbers satisfy a linear recurrence with constant coefficients in $\bar{\mathbb Q}$, then it also satisfy a linear recurrence with constant coefficients in ${\mathbb Q}$.

Let $(u_n)\in\mathbb Q^\mathbb N$ such that for all n :
$$ u_{n+p} = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} a_i u_{n+i} $$
for some $(a_i)\in \bar{\mathbb Q}^p$

The coefficients $(a_i)$ lie in a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$. Consider the trace form $Tr_{K/\mathbb Q}$. Then, for all n :
$$ d\cdot u_{n+p} = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}Tr_{K/\mathbb Q}(a_i) u_{n+i}, $$
with $d$ the degree of the extension.
**QED**.

**NOTE**

The same argument can be formulated without recurrences the following way :

- The elements of $L$ lying in $\mathbb Q((x))$ are the elements with **rational coefficients** ;
- The elements of $L$ lying in $\bar{\mathbb Q}(x)$ are the elements $u$ with no fractional power and s.t. **there exists $P \in \bar{\mathbb Q}[x]$ s.t. $uP$ is a polynomial** ;
- The elements of $L$ lying in $\mathbb Q(x)$ are the elements with no fractional power, **rational coefficients** and s.t. **there exists $P \in {\mathbb Q}[x]$ s.t. $uP$ is a polynomial**.

The same argument with traces works as well.